# Bosonization of $\beta \gamma$ system

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, conformal-field-theory, supersymmetry, ghosts

I am studying the bosonization of the $\beta \gamma$ ghost system, also called as the symplectic boson (See for example, [section 2.3 of this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0207201). These have OPE,
\begin{equation}
\beta(z) \gamma(w) \sim \frac{1}{z-w}
\end{equation}
and can be bosonized as,
$$\beta = e^{-i\phi} \eta, \quad \gamma= e^{-i\phi} \partial \xi$$
where $\phi$ is a free scalar boson, and $\eta, \xi$ are anti-commuting free fermions.
My question pertains to the bosonization of the $U(1)$ current of the $\beta \gamma$ system. This is given by the equation,
$$J=\frac{1}{2}:\beta \gamma:$$
After bosonization this reads,
$$J=\frac{1}{2}i \partial \phi.$$
(See for example the paragraph below equation (25) in the linked paper.)
I can't understand why the above equation is true? Why doesn't $\eta, \xi$ appear in the above equation. I understand that $$:e^{-i\phi}e^{i\phi}:\sim i\partial \phi$$
but what happens to the product $\eta \partial \xi$?

Is this equal to the identity operator and how do I see this?

**Attempt**
I tried bosonizing the $\eta, \xi$ fermions as,
$$\eta = e^{-\chi}, \quad \xi = e^{\chi}.$$
Then the product, $:\eta \partial \xi: = :e^{-\chi} e^{\chi} \partial \chi:=  :\partial \chi \partial \chi:$
where I have again used the bosonization,
$$:e^{-\chi} e^{\chi}: \sim \partial \chi$$
Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Good question, I think it works as follows. The OPEs are

$$e^{-i\phi(z)} e^{i\phi(z)} = (z-w) + (z-w)^2 i\partial \phi(w) + \dots$$

and

$$\eta(z)\partial\xi(w)=e^{-\chi(z)} \partial e^{\chi(w)} = \frac{1}{(z-w)^2} + \partial^2\chi(w) + \dots $$

Multiplying, subtracting poles, and taking the limit $z\to w$ yields $i\partial\phi$.